# Monotononically Increasing Water Filling Solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, affine-geometry

$\mathbf{I}$ is the $K\times K$ identity matrix.

$\mathbf{h}_i\in\mathbb{C}^{M\times1}\quad\forall1\leq i\leq K$ are column vectors.

Consider the solution of the convex optimisation problem over $\mathbf{x}=[x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_K]$
$$\mathbf{x}^*=\mbox{argmax}\log|\mathbf{I}+\sum_{i=1}^Kx_i\mathbf{h}_i\mathbf{h}_i^{\text{H}}|$$

under the constraints $x_i\geq0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^Kx_i=P$. 
Show that $\mathbf{x}^*$ is an element-wise non-decreasing function of $P$.

P. S. Basically the objective function is the multiple access channel data rate under a power constraint. I am trying to prove that if the available total power is increased, the optimally available power increases for each user $x_i$. This is intuitively obvious, but can't prove it.

Comment: I believe this is a well known result in wireless communication literature. Did you try to find any reference for this?

Comment: Yes, the result is accepted on an intuitive basis, but could not find any rigorous proof. By the way, it is easy to prove for parallel gaussian channels, but I am talking about interfering multiaccess channels. The difference is not relevant once the mathematical modelling is done though. I expressed it in a mathematical form so that it's appreciated by people not familiar with information theory.

Comment: This is a hunch. I think if we can prove it for two users, then by induction, we can prove it for $K$ users.